# How to calculate the latlon bounding boxes for many lat/lng locations?

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, cluster-analysis, bounding-box

I'm working with two databases, one with strike observations and an other one with many (lat,lng) locations.

I want to extract all strikes closed to my position. In order to speed up my SQL queries, I want to  limit my requests by working only over limited area (bounding boxes) around my positions and not requesting all strikes over the globe.

To do that, I m trying to define some limited areas .

In the picture below, the red dots are my reference positions and I would like to define/create with python bounding areas (yellow boxes) and get (latmin,latmax,lonmin,lonmax) for all bounding areas.

[image]

Do you have any python libraries I should start with ? I started with a clustering approach but with no success.

Comment: First you wrote about SQL queries and then about python. Could you elaborate on what you are working with?

Comment: Yes sure, I working with Python to run the process  and SQL where databases are stored...but actually I want to define/create bounding  boxes only with Python.